# Can't update homstead using vagrant box update

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I got this

```
==> default: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    default: Latest installed version: 0.3.3
    default: Version constraints: < 0.4.0
    default: Provider: virtualbox
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.3.3) is running the latest version.
```

When I do `vagrant box update`. I want php7 and ubuntu16, but what's causing the problem for me to upgrade my homestead?

Comment: I removed the PHP tag, because the core of your question is not related to [tag:PHP].

Comment: I found http://www.darwinbiler.com/keeping-your-homestead-box-up-to-date/ helpful. Bummed that I need to destroy my box every time I want to upgrade.